# Use libmediainfo in Mac XCode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to use [libmediainfo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/files/binary/libmediainfo0/0.7.61/) in an Xcode project but I'm unable to get it to work properly.

I've added the dylib to the Frameworks folder of my project and made sure it is added to the "Link Binary with Libraries" section in the build settings of the target.

Every time I try to build the app it says:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libmediainfo.0.dylib
  Referenced from: ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout loader path: otool -L libmediainfo.dylib

If it has @loader_path, change it to @rpath with install_name_tool

install_name_tool -id @rpath/libmediainfo.dylib libmediainfo.dylib

Or, you can place the dylib in the MacOS folder and use @executable_path instead of @rpath.